# How to run a background timer in Flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, kubernetes

I'm trying to write a [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) app that behaves correctly when running in [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/), especially when it comes to [graceful shutdown](https://blog.risingstack.com/graceful-shutdown-node-js-kubernetes/).

As such, I need to have the code:

- recieve the shutdown signal
- start the "shutdown timer"
- continue serving requests as normal until the time is "up"
- then shut itself down

So far, what I've got is this:

```
from flask import Flask, abort
import signal
import time
app = Flask(__name__)
shuttingDown = False

def exit_gracefully(self, signum):
    app.logger.error('Received shutdown signal. Exiting gracefully')
    global shuttingDown
    shuttingDown = True
    # TODO: wait for some time here to ensure we are not receiving any more
    # traffic
    time.sleep(20)
    exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_gracefully)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
        return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/_status/liveness")
def liveness():
        return "I am alive"

@app.route("/_status/readiness")
def readiness():
        if not shuttingDown:
            return "I am ready"
        else:
            abort(500, 'not ready anymore')
```

The above "works" except after I send the "shutdown" signal, regular requests to "/" are not responded to, even though we are still within the shutdown "grace period" (20 seconds in the above code).

It seems that the call to "time.sleep()" is synchronous.

Does anyone know of any way to make this "asynchronous"? So that the app continues to service requests until the time is "up"?

Comment: What do you use as your web server? This may be a silly question as I am not familiar with Kubernetes. Does it provide your HTTP server, or do you use the Flask internal server, WSGI or something else?

Comment: Am using the built-in Flask development server for the above.

Comment: See my modified answer below. It should do it, and it offers an alternative as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a guess you are using the builtin Flask development server. Such builtin development servers in Flask and Django, or anything based on the web server or WSGI server in the standard library are not intended for production systems and don't normally handle shutdown on signals properly.

As such, you should really use a proper production grade WSGI server such as Apache/mod_wsgi (mod_wsgi-express), gunicorn or uWSGI. These all handle signals properly and you don't have the issue with the development servers where they ignore the signal causing the container shutdown to be delayed, with it eventually being killed by Kubernetes when the shutdown timeout occurs.

Comment: Indeed, I was trying to test this behaviour locally using the build it Flask server. Regarding using the above, would there be any way to configure the "wait time" between when the WSGI server receives the signal and when it starts shutting down?

Comment: How long are your requests? Apache/mod_wsgi at least gives a few seconds in normal case to allow current requests to complete before processes are forcibly shutdown. If you need better control over draining a specific instance of requests, you really need to manage it separate to use of signals. You would need to send a request to the application, which triggers subsequent sending of a fail response to a readiness probe so Kubernetes removes it from active endpoints of service so receives no new traffic.

Comment: Through a timeout or monitoring of active requests, when drained, server could exit or kill itself causing the instance to be replaced. All up it really depends on what you are trying to do. You may be better of using green/blue deployments where start up separate instances and then control where requests go at the route/ingress so new traffic is switched to new instances. After a while, then shutdown old instances. You just obviously need more resources available for that since have duplication of number of instances required.

Comment: > need to manage it separate to use of signals
Kubernetes sends the signal. Indicating to the app "you're about to be shut down". The above code receives the signal and starts responding with a HTTP500 on the "readiness" endpoint to indicate to Kubernetes it should no longer have requests routed to it.

The app knows (through config) that if if continues to send HTTP500 in response to "readiness" probes for 10 seconds (for example), Kubernetes will stop routing traffic to it at which point it can safely clean up and shut down.

Comment: Therefore, this is essentially Inter Process Communication between Kubernetes and the Container using a mixture of UNIX signals, HTTP requests and configuration to ensure both sides behave gracefully in shutdown (app doesn't exit too early, while traffic still being routed to it) and Kubernetes does not kill the app while it might be in the middle of dealing with a request.

I suppose that I'm going to have to consult the documentation for whatever WSGI server I choose to find if/where/how the timeout can be configured and how to trigger shutdown (I would like the app to handle the signal)

Comment: Your application code which initially receives the HTTP request and starts the whole process off to tell the application to start shutting down, can simply do ``os.kill(1, signal.SIGTERM)`` at the end, process ID 1 being the main application process in the container. That would then cause the server to really shutdown and thus the container exit, causing it to restart. So there isn't a need to have shutdown timeout of server configurable, it just needs to stop on signal and not ignore it.

Comment: The application doesn't receive an "HTTP request" from Kubernetes to say that it's about to be shut down. It receives a SIGTERM signal. This isn't configurable (e.g. you can't specify that it should receive an HTTP request as the "shutdown hook" instead). Therefore, the app needs to "catch" the sigterm (rather than the WSGI server), wait some amount of time to ensure that there aren't any requests "in flight" and then shutdown (call os.exit() or os.kill(1) etc...).

Comment: I am saying if you want to be able to manage a restart/shutdown in a more controlled way, relying on waiting for the signal may not be the best way. You can always trigger the HTTP request, or do it by executing a command in the container, by using a ``preStop`` lifecycle hook if using Kubernetes or OpenShift. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods

Comment: Using a ``preStop``, you don't even need to do the final kill of the application as you just need to delay the response of the ``preStop`` action until you are happy that you can shutdown as requests have been drained. As part of the shutdown sequence with a ``preStop``, Kubernetes will even remove the instance from the service endpoints for you.

Comment: oh, right! Yes, that makes absolute sense. I was not aware of the "preStop" lifecycle hook at all! Thank you very much, this makes things much simpler!

Answer (score 1):

This works with the internal server. The caveat is there is a /_shutdown URL that shuts the server down, and this is open to malicious shutdowns. If this is not what you want, then remove `requests.post()` and uncomment `os._exit()`. And of course remove `@app.route("/_shutdown")` and the function as well.

```
from flask import Flask, abort, request
import signal
import threading
import time
import os
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)
shuttingDown = False


def exit_call():
    time.sleep(20)
    requests.post("http://localhost:5420/_shutdown")
    # os._exit(0)


def exit_gracefully(self, signum):
    app.logger.error('Received shutdown signal. Exiting gracefully')
    global shuttingDown
    shuttingDown = True
    # TODO: wait for some time here to ensure we are not receiving any more
    # traffic
    _et = threading.Thread(target=exit_call)
    _et.daemon = True
    _et.start()


signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_gracefully)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
        return "Hello World!"


@app.route("/_status/liveness")
def liveness():
        return "I am alive"


@app.route("/_shutdown", methods=["POST"])
def shutdown():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        return "Not a werkzeug server"
    func()
    return "shutdown"


@app.route("/_status/readiness")
def readiness():
        if not shuttingDown:
            return "I am ready"
        else:
            abort(500, 'not ready anymore')


app.run(port=5420)
```